# Store Decision Tree Code / Algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have an assignment for which I am planning on using machine learning (supervised learning in particular, such as a decision tree). The final code will be run on a Teaching Assistant's pc which doesn't have scikit learn or other external libraries.

As such, I need to either write something like a decision tree classifier from scratch, or use an external library locally, and store the final algorithm.

To summarize: When given a set of labelled training data, how do you store the final algorithm in python code, without relying on external libraries to run the final algorithm in the future?

For example, a decision tree can be broken down to a series of if/then statements, I want to generate those if/then statements and store them so that it can be run on a computer with nothing installed except python.

What is the best recommendation on how to achieve this. If this is in the wrong forum please advise.

Comment: I think this is the right forum since your problem mainly involves implementing a machine learning algorithm in a language (Python).

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Is it "how do I encapsulate my dependencies so the code can be run on another computer without installing anything (apart from python)?"?

Comment: Yeah, basically I want a series of if/then statements for the decision tree algorithm (as an example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python random forest package `sklearn.ensemble` as follows:

```
# Import the random forest package
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 

# create a random forest object with 100 trees
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)

predictors = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
response = [0, 1]

# fit the model to the training data
forest = forest.fit(predictors, response)

# you can reuse the forest model you built to make predictions
# on other data sets
test_data = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
output = forest.predict(test_data)
```

Note that I imported `RandomForestClassifier` here, but you could have also used `RandomForestRegressor` in case you wanted run random forests in regression mode instead.